# What solid alternatives are there to Django's `UniqueConstraint` with a condition?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

**Goal:**

I want to ensure there is only one active `owner` per `Thing`.

**Problem:**

As our DB is MySQL, I can't use the `condition` parameter of Django's `UniqueConstraint`. I'm looking for a reliable, scalable alternative to this:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['owner'],
                condition=Q(active=True),
                name='one_active_owner_per_thing'
            )
        ]
```

Would it be best to create a separate table for active `Thing`s, override the save method, or something else?

Comment: Well MySQL supports `CHECK` (so this), since version 8.0.16.

Comment: You can perhaps store the `Thing` as `ForeignKey` from the `User`, then you do not need a check, a `User` simply refers to its active `Thing`.